# Place span element next to image, but at the center vertically

Tags: css

I'd like to have an image slideshow with a next button that forms the entire right border of the image. Would it be possible to have the words "NEXT" display in the center of the red area, instead of on the same line as the image?

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <span>NEXT</span>
</ul>

li {
    display: block;
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    display: inline-block;
    border:1px solid;
}
span {
    background-color:red;
    padding-top:100px;
}
```

Fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/PUQNg/217/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few things wrong with your HTML and CSS that you should correct:

- `span` is not a valid child of `ul`, make this a `li` instead
- There's no point having `display: block;` and `display: inline-block;` on `li`, only the last `display` property will be used

To centralise the text in this case I would use a `line-height` set to the `height` of the li.

```css
li {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 200px;
}
.next {
    background-color: red;
    border: 0;
    line-height: 100px;
    width: auto;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li class="next">NEXT</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! Now I understand how to do this :)